# C# WPF добавить элемент управления из nuget

Tags: c#, wpf, nuget

Установил nuget пакет https://github.com/Dirkster99/NumericUpDownLib с компонентом NumericUpDown, но не могу понять как мне добавить его в проект чтобы я мог разместить его на форме. Заранее благодарю

Comment: Там ведь есть документация, с примерами. А вообще, любой компонент XAML прописывается так: `<пространствоИмен:Название/>` где `пространствоИмен` - это некая строка сверху, в свойствах окна (обычно ее генерирует студия, если нажать на красное выделение).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ там примеры без описания чего либо, на впф еще разбираюсь что к чему.  Про выделение не понял, у меня синим выделяет ошибку, написано В типе "ResourceDictionary" не удалось найти присоединяемое свойство "MergedDictionaries".

Comment: Плохо смотрите. Открываем [WiKi](https://github.com/Dirkster99/NumericUpDownLib/wiki), видим сразу весь список доступных контролов, ниже, весь список доступных свойств с их описанием. Также есть [Demo](https://github.com/Dirkster99/NumericUpDownLib/tree/master/source/Demo), где авторы любезно предоставили по всем контролам различные примеры, допустим вот простой [NumericUpDown](https://github.com/Dirkster99/NumericUpDownLib/blob/master/source/Demo/UpDownDemoLib/Views/NumericUpDownDemo.xaml#L26). Зачем вы лезете в словари, мне лично не понятно, ведь это, если почитаете, относится к темам.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо помогли. Решил про ресурсы потому что в примере использования написано
Load Light or Dark brush resources in you resource dictionary to take advantage of existing definitions.

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/NumericUpDownLib;component/Themes/DarkBrushs.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/NumericUpDownLib;component/Themes/LightBrushs.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>